# Change the frame of a custom table view cell's button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I display a list of items for sale in a UITableView. If the user didn't set a description on an item, I would like to adjust the positioning of some of the elements in the cell to adjust for the blank label.

The following code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't working.

```
cell.productName.text = product.fields[@"title"];
cell.productPrice.text = product.fields[@"price"];
cell.productDescription.text = vehicle.fields[@"salespersonComments"];

if ([cell.productDescription.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    CGRect f = cell.favoriteButton.frame;
    f.origin.y = 10; // new y
    cell.favoriteButton.frame = f;

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You have to use the UITableView delegate methods
//Method for displaying the cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

    }

//Method for adjusting the cell height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return 80;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than physically changing the coordinated/frame of the item, it would be better to have `IBOutlets` connected to the relevant `NSLayoutConstraint`s.

Then you could do something like:

```
if ([cell.productDescription.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    cell.favoriteButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.leadingIndentConstraint.constant = 0;

} else {

}
```